# Is `reinterpret_cast` for pointer and reference conversion completely superceded by features from new C++ standard?

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

`reinterpret_cast` in C++ is considered dangerous by many people and it is hard to use it correctly without invoking UB. It also has various different usages and fail to convey the intention behind the cast well. Recent standards have added a lot of features that aims at type conversion preserving the underlying object representation, including but may not be limited to [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), [`std::span::as_bytes` and `std:span::as_writable_bytes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/as_bytes), as well as [`std::start_lifetime_as` and `std::start_lifetime_as_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as). This makes me wonder whether there are any reasons for `reinterpret_cast` usages corresponding to these in newer code.

Maybe the question title is not entirely accurate, but I am interested in whether there are any practical use for `reinterpret_cast` in newer code that corresponds to items 7 and 11 (and maybe also 10) in [the standard draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast). I am interested in a detailed answer stating how each usage is or is not superceded and what is the recommended way in place of them in the case they are superceded. I am aware that there are many other uses for `reinterpret_cast` that are not superseded by new features in the language.

> 7. An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.<sup>57</sup> When a prvalue v of object pointer type is
>    converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is
>    static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v)).
> 8. ...
> 9. ...
> 10. A prvalue of type “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to
>     member of Y of type T2” if T1 and T2 are both function types or both
>     object types.<sup>58</sup> The null member pointer value ([conv.mem]) is
>     converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type.
>     The result of this conversion is unspecified, except in the following
>     cases:
>
> - Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a different pointer-to-member-function type and back to its original type yields the original pointer-to-member value.
> - Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to data member of X of type T1” to the type “pointer to data member of Y of type T2” (where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer-to-member value.
>
> 11. A glvalue of type T1, designating an object x, can be cast to the type “reference to T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be
>     explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a
>     reinterpret_cast. The result is that of *reinterpret_cast<T2 *>(p)
>     where p is a pointer to x of type “pointer to T1”. No temporary is
>     created, no copy is made, and no constructors ([class.ctor]) or
>     conversion functions ([class.conv]) are called.<sup>59</sup>

---

> <sup>57</sup> The types can have different cv-qualifiers, subject to the overall restriction that a reinterpret_cast cannot cast away constness. 
> <sup>58</sup> T1 and T2 can have different cv-qualifiers, subject to the overall restriction that a reinterpret_cast cannot cast away constness. 
> <sup>59</sup> This is sometimes referred to as a type pun when the result refers to the same object as the source glvalue.

Comment: You ask three different questions. :) `reinterpret_cast` in general, `reinterpret_cast` with meaning corresponding to one of the standard functions listed, and `reinterpret_cast` using bullets 7 or 11.

Comment: All it takes is one library function that disagrees what the byte type should be. E.g. zlib thinks `unsigned char` is the byte type. The standard library now seems to like `std::byte`. Something else in the standard library probably uses `char`.

Comment: I actually want to ask the third, the others are motivations (if you find it strange to use them as motivation, then probably I have some deep misunderstanding). Any suggestions on clearing up the wording?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The `zlib` example as a use case is a good enough partial answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bit_cast` and `std::start_lifetime_as` don't *replace* `reinterpret_cast`, they are new capabilities that `reinterpret_cast` never had. `std::span::as_bytes` is a convenience function, which is as much to help with `std::dynamic_extent` as it is to wrap the cast.

So the useful usages of `reinterpret_cast` haven't changed. What has changed is there are defined behaviour replacements for constructs where people were using `reinterpret_cast` with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is it always possible to rewrite valid uses of `reinterpret_cast` for item 7 and 11 with `span::as_bytes`? I believe at least the latter shows the intention better.

Comment: @WeijunZhou you only get `std::span<std::byte>` back from `span::as_bytes`, any valid `reinterpret_cast` with a destination type that isn't `std::byte` isn't helped by that.

Comment: @WeijunZhou The thing is, there are *barely any* valid uses of `reinterpret_cast` from item 7 and 11, and they mostly involve *not using* the casted-to object